# Prevent directory clean in Ember-CLI

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I am using ember-cli from within a Java project. I am trying to build into a directory other than `dist/`. I am setting the path using `"output-path": "../src/main/resources"` in `.ember-cli`. The project is building and being output into the proper directory. The problem is that this directory has other things in it that are being cleaned when I do the ember build.

Is there a way to stop the clean, or better yet, to white list some files and directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the CLI code, it seems it is not possible.

https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/blob/master/lib/models/builder.js#L50

```
  /**
    This is used to ensure that the output path is emptied, but not deleted
    itself. If we simply used `remove(this.outputPath)`, any symlinks would
    now be broken. This iterates the direct children of the output path,
    and calls `remove` on each (this preserving any symlinks).
  */
  clearOutputPath: function() {
    var outputPath = this.outputPath;
    if (!fs.existsSync(outputPath)) { return Promise.resolve();}

    if(!this.canDeleteOutputPath(outputPath)) {
      return Promise.reject(new SilentError('Using a build destination path of `' + outputPath + '` is not supported.'));
    }

    var promises = [];
    var entries = fs.readdirSync(outputPath);

    for (var i = 0, l = entries.length; i < l; i++) {
      promises.push(remove(path.join(outputPath, entries[i])));
    }

    return Promise.all(promises);
  }
```